# how to update a nullable column in sql server stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, procedure

I have a stored procedure that takes care of updates to my person table.  I don't always update every column so I've provided default values (null) for some of the procedure parameters.  But, what if I really want to set the person.middleinitial to null?  How does the procedure know my intent?

In reality my person table has LOTS of columns and many are nullable so this can become burdensom depending on the solution.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspPerson_update]     
@id uniqueidentifier,     
@fname nvarchar(20) = NULL,     
@minitial nvarchar(1) = NULL,     
@lname nvarchar(20) = NULL 
AS BEGIN     
SET NOCOUNT ON;     
UPDATE Person      
SET 
fname=ISNULL(@fname,fname),          
minitial=ISNULL(@minitial,minitial),          
lname=ISNULL(@lname, lname)
WHERE id=@id 
END
```

Comment: You could add flags, e.g. '@SetMI as Bit = 0', that indicate your intent to apply a value.  The 'UPDATE' statement would use a 'CASE' to determine whether to recycle the old value or apply the new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't set initials to `NULL`, set them to a zero length/empty string `''`.

Then you can tell the difference between "not specified" (`NULL`) and "no initial" (`''`).

Comment: What would I do about numbers and dates and other non-character columns?

Comment: @akaDka : You either need to choose *special* values (1900-01-01 for dates, -1 for integers, etc) or have dedicated code to *clear* a field. It depends on your business logic, use cases, etc. A very hacky option is to pass everything as a string, and so still be able to use the empty string method, but that is nasty.

Comment: Yes, very nasty especially for binary ;)  I'm looking at using an integer parameter that I can bitwise (&) to determine intent.

Comment: @akaDka : That would come under the specialised code option.  Parameter pairs, one indicating intent, one with the value.  Using an INT to collate all the flags is efficient in terms of data volume, but probably adds as much overhead as it saves in terms of time.  I'd stick to one parameter per flag ;)